# Strongly named assemblies in bin folder on ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, gac, strongname

I know not to put strongly named assemblies into the bin folder on early versions of ASP.NET.  I remember this caused problems, but I don't remember specifically what problems.  Does anyone know if this still applies to ASP.NET 2.0?  Is there any reason not to put strongly named assemblies into the bin folder on ASP.NET 2.0 or later versions?

Comment: I've been putting strongly-named assemblies in the `bin` folder of web applications since ASP.NET 2.0, and never encountered any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe was fixed on .NET 2.0, so you don't need to worry about it anymore.

However, beware that if you put a strong-named assembly in the `bin` folder, and an assembly with the same strong name exists in the GAC, then the assembly in the GAC will get loaded.

Comment: that's not entirely correct since his assemblies have different versions and the GAC is version aware. So only if the assembly he's using is also in the GAC will it matter. But that's the whole point of the question since he doesn't want to put it in the GAC.

Comment: Actually strong name **consists of** the assembly name and version already (and culture) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems with this. I've done it a few times during development/testing and I even have a site currently running that has strongly named assemblies in the bin folder with no issues.

Assemblies are strongly named for a reason (obviously) so you should have a good reason to drop them in the bin folder.

Comment: I do have a good reason to drop them in the .bin folder.  This server is hosting 2 other production websites using different versions of the assemblies.  I don't think loading them in the GAC will take down those sites, but I don't want to find out if I am right.

Comment: The thing with strongly named assemblies is that they are versioned. So if your app is using a different version from the other apps, there should be no issues. That's the whole point of the GAC. Each ASP.NET app will have the version of these assemblies they expect to find so you can take a look at their web.config files and confirm.

Comment: You know for this app it's not an issue, but lets say in the future other apps need the version you're using and let's say in the future there is another version of the assemblies everyone is using. That's when someone has to know/remember that one of those assemblies is in one of those bin folders and so you're not seeing the new features. It'll just get to be a mess in the long run.

Comment: "there should be no issues" - I agree, but another developer does not want to take that chance.

Comment: "It'll just get to be a mess in the long run"  All the websites should use the same version of this assembly, and it should be in the GAC.  This is a temporary fix.

Comment: So as I said earlier. There is no issue dropping a strongly named assembly in the bin folder of an app. I've done this a few times and I can confirm that it works. I was simply trying to address your second question about "issues". Not issues other than maintenance related.

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced problems with strong named assemblies being put into the bin. I have experienced some Interop problems with strong named assemblies and versioning conflicts, but those were caused by developers compiling older versions of an ComPlus application library into the solution instead of the current or newer version.

Comment: I have jumped off a cliff without getting hurt.  That does not mean it is safe for everyone all the time.

Comment: @Brad - Tru dat, but I've read fairly thoroughly (IMO) on strong named assemblies, and nothing I came across indicated that strong named assemblies are detrimental to the bin (which is why I jumped off that cliff in the first place). I am admittedly no expert in strong named assemblies, though.